# how can I use doGet response inside a method?

Tags: java, servlets, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to use response.flushbuffer inside method with selenium.

my code

```
static PrintWriter writer;
static int timer = 0;

protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
{
    runDriver("radio", "click", "complete");
}

public static void runDriver(String col1, String Col2, String col3)
{
    WebElement ack1 = driver.findElement(By.id("represent"));
    try
    {
        ack1.click();
        String click1 = "<tr><td>" + col1 + "</td><td>" + col2 + "</td><td>" + col3 + "</td></tr>";
        writer.println(click1);
        response.flushBuffer(); // Won't let me put this here!
        Thread.sleep(timer);                                                                                        
     }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
        writer.println( e+" ID:21");
    }
}
```

what I am trying to is isolate the same actions by Webdriver to one method so that i dont have to repeat it. I also tried doing it like this.

```
static PrintWriter writer;
static int timer = 0;

protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
{
    String radio1 = "Radio";
    String clicked = "Click";
    String complete = " Complete";

    top(radio1, clicked, complete);
    response.flushBuffer();
    bottom();
}

    public static void top(String col1, String col2, String col3)
    {
        writer.println("<tr><td>" + col1 + "</td><td>" + col2 + "</td><td>" + col3 + "</td></tr>");
    }

    public static void bottom()
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(timer);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            writer.println( "error: " + e);
        }
    }
```

but it gave me a NullPointerException. The reason I need to use response.flushBuffer() is so the user can see the process as it happens. Otherwise it would complete the process then output text.

Update **

I fixed the NPE. It turns out I still had Printer writer declared inside the doget method. I still can get response.flushbuffer outside the doget method.

Comment: I think you don't understand variable scope. You are also confusing how selenium should be used to test servlets.

Comment: I know that a variable can't be accessed unless it is a global variable. I was trying to see if there is a way to put flushbuffer inside the top() method. How would you accomplish this?

Comment: basically im running selenium off a JSP page. so a use would go to the page and it would run the webdriver to do certain tasks. Thats why there is output of radio, clicked, and complete. Not really testing servlets.

Comment: Why do you have `doGet` methods? What `HttpServletResponse` `OutputStream` do you think you are flushing?

Comment: i only pasted a very small portion of the app. the `doGet` is used to output text to the person who loaded the JSP page. it will go to a `driver.get(URL)` and do certain tasks like copy paste into a form. and the `doGet()` will output to the page text such as "loaded webpage", "clicked on radio button", clicked on textbox, enter firstname into textbox, etc.... and flushing allows me to output after each task. so when `webdriver` clicks radio button i use `response.flushbuffer` before going to the next step.

Comment: Where and why do you think your `doGet()` will be called?

Comment: thats not my issue. I export it from eclipse as a .war and place on tomcat7. what I am trying to do here is use response.flushbuffer outside doget, is this possible?

Comment: We are on different pages. Which response's buffer do you think you are flushing?

Comment: the one in the doGet(), right? I just want it in the method runDriver() so it can be after the `writer.println(click1);`

Comment: And what is calling your `doGet()`?

Comment: now im confused. What you mean exactly?

Comment: What's your entry point? How is `doGet()` getting called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, be aware that global variables inside a servlet are shared by all requests and can lead to thread safety issues. Except for a few use cases (e.g. a global counter) it is almost always a bad idea to use them in a servlet.

Why don't you simply pass the `response` object to the `top()` method? For example:

```
public static void top(String col1, String col2, String col3, HttpServletResponse response)
{
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.println("<tr><td>" + col1 + "</td><td>" + col2 + "</td><td>" + col3 + "</td></tr>");
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```